# Localization in ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to create dynamic message using property from property file and merge value from query result in it.

eg: Hi! This is **Dinesh**

To show this message in report I will create one properties file say test.properties. It will contain 
MSG = Hi! this is {0}

Then while running report I will pass argument String as "Dinesh" to replace {0}

This procedure we follow for to display dynamic message in JSP. How can I implement it in iReport?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!! :)

We can use it as:

msg(str("MSG"),"Dinesh")

we can replace direct String "Dinesh" with variable like $F{test2}.
Where $F{test2} is a field returned from sql query..